# JavaScript Command

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a link automatically click after x seconds for my website. However, my following code does not work:

```
<body alink="#84868a" onLoad="setTimeout('delayer()', 1000)">  

<script type="text/javascript">
function delayer(){document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();}
</script>

                                    <div class="navBtns mar9 s3">

                                         <a href="#" class="prev"><span></span></a>
                                         <a href="#" class="next" id="myButtonId"><span></span></a>

                                    </div>

                                </div> 
                            </div>
```

I'm not great with JavaScript so if somebody could assist that would be great!

Comment: Remove second '=' at onLoad==

Comment: Hi, the second '=' has been removed however, nothing happens. What should happen is there is a side menu filled with links, the action should automatically run the "next" button link command therefore changing the menu to page two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onLoad==` need to have only one `=`
also `click()` is jQuery function, are you pre-loading it?

This is working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mgc5mqfa/

Comment: Ah! This is almost what I need and want! However, does it have to display a popup? Can it not just be a command that mimics a user clicking a link or button?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with it after the click event fired with: 
```$('body').on('click','#myButtonId',finction(){ 
DO WHATEVER YOU NEED HERE 
});```

Comment: Awesome! I got it working!! Thank you so much! One more quick question though, is there a repeat function for the onload? Say repeat the function after x seconds?

Comment: OnLoad is firing on windows load, so it fires only once unless page refreshes, I guess you may use something like `window.onload = function() { DO YOUR STUFF AND RELOAD THE PAGE after };` but it is very bad practice to overload the user like that.

Answer (score -2):

If you console log your document.getElementById it should return null. Thats because the javascript hasn't seen the node in the dom yet. Put your script at the bottom of your page and see if that fixes it.

Comment: The function is _supposed_ to be executed on `load` event.